# To make a map of sinkholes on grass gis

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology, hydrography

I would like to make a map of sinkholes. I have a  DTM ARC/INFO ASCII GRID of Asiago Plateau and and I'm using grass gis. Does anyone know what is the correct form in grass gis?

Comment: Please take a look at this page why sink filling is not needed in GRASS GIS: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences#Sink_filling:_why_not_needed_in_GRASS_GIS

Comment: Thanks, I read. I understood that it was necessary to consider the areas highlighted as a fault. I was not happy with the result and so looking at the DEM I saw that large sinkholes could be seen by eye. The area that I have analyzed is not large and karst features are well developed. From a DEM with cells to 5 meters I could not expect much more.

Comment: Fortunately I'm a caver and I can make out the sinkholes from rough terrain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to create a map of sinkholes using a DEM, you would first fill the topographic depressions (sinkholes) then difference the original DEM from the filled DEM. This gives you 'depth in sink' but if you simply want a Boolean sink map, reclass the depth map such that 1 is assigned to all values greater than 0. The tool in GRASS GIS to fill depressions is called [r.fill.dir](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/r.fill.dir.html). As an aside, in ArcGIS there is a convenient tool that maps sinks in one step by using the **[Sink](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000054000000.htm)** tool and in the open-source GIS [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml), for which I am a developer, you can use the similarly named **[Sink](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/Sink.html)** tool to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Filippo That's great. I'm glad you got solved.